# Как правильно определить операции, что компилятор не уходил в warning?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно поправить такую ошибку(да, на самом деле это варнинг, но все же)? Суть в том , что создал свой класс, для него определил операции, в качестве результат операций возвращаю объект класса, который был создан внутри. Ниже привожу ошибку, оператор присваивания, операции и определение класса, привел реализацию функций, которые могут повлиять на появление данной ошибки. Не совсем понимаю,в чем именно проблема.

**Ошибка**

```
functions.cpp: In member function 'IntPlaneSet IntPlaneSet::operator^(const IntPlaneSet&)':
                                       
14:06functions.cpp:58:12: error: implicitly-declared 'constexpr IntPlaneSet::IntPlaneSet(const IntPlaneSet&)' is deprecated [-Werror=deprec ated-copy]                                                                                                                                58 |     return r;                                                                                                                        |            ^                                                                                                                   functions.cpp:30:14: note: because 'IntPlaneSet' has user-provided 'IntPlaneSet& IntPlaneSet::operator=(const IntPlaneSet&)'              30 | IntPlaneSet& IntPlaneSet::operator=(const IntPlaneSet& a)                                                                            |              ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Оператор присваивания**

```
IntPlaneSet& IntPlaneSet::operator=(const IntPlaneSet& a)
{
    SetZero();
    CopyOnly(a);
    return *this;

}
```

**Операция**

```
IntPlaneSet IntPlaneSet::operator^(const IntPlaneSet& a)
{
    IntPlaneSet r = IntPlaneSet(max(this->x1,a.x1),max(this->x2,a.x2),max(this->y1,a.y1),max(this->y2,a.y2));
    r.b_s = this->b_s ^ a.b_s;
    return r;
}
```

**Так определен класс**

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
#define x_1 -10
#define y_1 -10
#define x_2 -10
#define y_2 10
#define x_3 10 //допустимые границы, в которых можно задать множество задаются жестко в начале программы
#define y_3 -10
#define x_4 10
#define y_4 10
#define x_size x_3 - x_1 + 1
#define y_size y_2 - y_1 + 1
#define SIZE (x_size)*(y_size)//размер bitset
#define TEST 2 //число массивов в тесте

using namespace std;

class IntPlaneSet
{
    int x1,x2,y1,y2;
    public:

        bitset<SIZE> b_s;
        
        class iterator
        {
            int cur;
            IntPlaneSet* S;
            public:
                iterator(IntPlaneSet *a= NULL)
                {
                    if (a!=NULL)
                    {
                        this->cur = a->FirstNonZero();
                        this->S = a;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this->cur = -1;
                        this->S=NULL;
                    }

                }

                int operator!=(const iterator &b);
                
                int operator==(const iterator &b);

                void operator++();


                void operator++(int);
                
                pair<int, int> operator*();

        };

        IntPlaneSet(int x1=x_1,int x2=x_3,int y1=y_1, int y2=y_2,int rand_key = 0 )
        {
            this->x1=x1;
            this->x2=x2;
            this->y1=y1;
            this->y2=y2;
            this->b_s=( 0 );
            if (rand_key == 1)
            {
                std::random_device rd;
                std::mt19937 rng(rd());
                std::uniform_int_distribution<int> ValsX(x1,x2);
                std::uniform_int_distribution<int> ValsY(y1,y2);
                for(int i = 0;i<abs(x2-x1)*abs(y2-y1);i++)
                {
                    int x=ValsX(rng);
                    int y = ValsY(rng);
                    int index =  ((y - y_1)*((x_3 - x_1)+1)) + ((x - x_1));
                    this->b_s[index]=1;
                }

            }


        }
        ~IntPlaneSet()
        {
            this->SetZero();
        }
        void SetZero()
        {
            this->b_s = ( 0 );
        }
        
        pair<int, int> GetValue(int a);

        void AddValue(const int x,const int y);

        void DeleteValue(const int x,const int y);

        void Print()
        {
            int index=0;
            cout << "Bitset : ( "<< this->b_s << " )\n"<< endl;
            
            for(int i=y_2;i>y_1-1;i--)
            {
                for (int j=x_1;j<x_3+1;j++)
                {
                    index =  ((i - y_1)*((x_3 - x_1)+1)) + ((j - x_1));
                    cout << this->b_s[index] << " ";
                }
                printf("\n");
                
            }



        }

        void Check(const int x,const int y);

        int* Borders();

        void ChangeBorders(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);

        void ChangeBorders(int* a);
        
        int** MinMax();

        IntPlaneSet operator&(const IntPlaneSet& a);

        IntPlaneSet operator|(const IntPlaneSet& a);

        IntPlaneSet operator^(const IntPlaneSet& a);

        IntPlaneSet operator~();

        void CopyOnly(const IntPlaneSet& a);

        IntPlaneSet& operator=(const IntPlaneSet& a);

        int FirstNonZero();

        int NextNonZero(int a);

        iterator begin()
        {
            return iterator(this);
        }

        iterator end()
        {
            return iterator(NULL);
        }
};
```

Comment: Покажите определение класса. В идеале, нужно соорудить [mcve] - короткую программу, которая демонстрирует ошибку (вместо нарезки из отдельных функций).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, компилятор мне выдает эту ошибку до всякой работы функции (ругается на то, как определены сами функции), поэтому программу ,демонстрирующую ошибку тут привести проблематично, но окей, поправлю вопрос, добавлю весь класс.

Comment: Выкидывайте куски программы, пока ошибка не пропадет.

Comment: Мне удалось выяснить, что виноват оператор присваивания, без него даже вроде все работает, но как его в таком случае корректно определить? Этого я пока не понимаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы написали для своего класса деструктор и копирующий оператор присваивания, но не написали копирующий конструктор, и перемещающие конструктор и оператор присваивания.

Поэтому... (см. ряды "destructor" и "copy assignment")

[image: pic]
<sup>(за таблицу спасибо Говарду Хиннанту)</sup>

Поэтому компилятор не стал генерировать перемещающие операции (5,6 колонки).

Но копирующий конструктор сгенерировал (3 колонка), хотя это поведение считается устаревшим (deprecated), начиная с C++11.

А вы где-то использовали этот копирующий конструктор, поэтому компилятор вас и предупреждает, что надеяться на его наличие не стоит.

Решение - убрать самодельный деструктор и копирующее присваивание. Все равно они ничего полезного не делают.

---

Если бы в них было что-то полезное, то есть другой вариант: явно попросить компилятор сгенерировать недостающие операции

```
IntPlaneSet(const IntPlaneSet &) = default;
IntPlaneSet(IntPlaneSet &&) = default;
// IntPlaneSet &operator=(const IntPlaneSet &) = default;
IntPlaneSet &operator=(IntPlaneSet &&) = default;
// ~IntPlaneSet() = default;
```

---

Советую почитать про [правило трех/пяти/нуля](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Народная мудрость гласит, что у класса должны быть, на выбор:

- Деструктор и копирующие операции (всего 3)
- Деструктор и копирующие и перемещающие операции (всего 5)
- Ничего из пяти - самый распространенный вариант (0)

А если комбинация какая-то другая, то это почти всегда ошибка, как в вашем случае.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> IntPlaneSet r = IntPlaneSet(max(this->x1,a.x1),max(this->x2,a.x2),max(this->y1,a.y1),max(this->y2,a.y2));
> ```

```
IntPlaneSet r(max(this->x1,a.x1),max(this->x2,a.x2),max(this->y1,a.y1),max(this->y2,a.y2));
```

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, что это за конструкция и почему она должна работать?

Comment: @RGeorgy, вызов конструктора. А чего бы ей не работать?